# Change keyboard layout by shortcut (text mode only)

Tags: linux, keyboard, gentoo, text-user-interface

I've got brand new gentoo on my box. No X installed. I want to know correct way to setup changing keyboard layout while in text mode. (Basically I need a simple way of cycling between three keyboard layouts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to edit `/etc/conf.d/keymap` file

for ex:

- Spanish key board

  `KEYMAP="es"`
- US keyboard

  `KEYMAP="us"`

#### Edit :

You can setup alias to quickly switch from one keyboard layout to another. 
You have to edit `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` (located in your home directory)
 `~/.bashrc` aka `$HOME/.bashrc` aka `/home/$USER/.bashrc`

```
alias kbd1="loadkeys /usr/lib/kbd/keytables/dvorak.map"
alias kbd2="loadkeys /usr/lib/kbd/keytables/us.map"
```

or

```
alias kbd1="sudo loadkeys qwerty"
alias kbd2="sudo loadkeys dvorak"
```

I haven't setup the hot keys as the way you are looking for. But, I can give you a reference. Check this page ==> [Hot key setup on console](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO.html)

You should be careful while setting up hotkeys as they should not affect the existing keys used by other drivers like tty.
for ex: these keys reserved by the consoles

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>C</kbd>  : Cancels current running command

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>D</kbd>  : Logs out of the current session

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd>  : Stops all output on screen (XOFF)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>W</kbd>  : Deletes the last word typed

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>U</kbd>  : Erases the complete line.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Q</kbd>  : Turns all output stopped on screen back on (XON)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>F</kbd>  : Moves the cursor forward one character

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>P</kbd>  : Paste previous line(s)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>B</kbd>  : Moves the cursor backward one character

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>H</kbd>  : Erase one character. Similar to pressing backspace

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Z</kbd>  : Cancels current operation, moves back a directory or takes the current operation and moves it to the background

Comment: but how I can assign the shortcut to switch between them without changing this file all the time?

Comment: @d3day, updated my answer.

Comment: yeah this is much better. but is there a way to assign this aliases to a keyboard shortcut so I'll be able to hit ctrl+shift and the alias will get executed? Not sure but I think there were such possibility in debian after some sort of magic, just wondering how to get it in gentoo.

Comment: yes, that can be done. you have to assign the key combinations in `~/.inputrc` file.

Comment: probably last question:
is `loadkeys` a part of X infrastructure, because I will not have X installed in my setup? Will I be able to use it in my conditions? Just want to confirm it before getting into action.

Comment: @d3day,  for X infra `xmodmap` will be used.